# bash operator for logical defined-or

Tags: perl, bash, assignment-operator, logical-operators

Is there an equivalent Bash operator to Perl's logical defined-or?  Something akin to:

```
$a = $a // $b;
```

OR

```
$a ||= $b;
```

Comment: `$a ||= $b;` is equivalent to `$a = $a || $b;`. `$a = $a // $b;` compacts to `$a //= $b;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Assign Default Values" parameter expansion.

```
echo "${foo:=42}"
```

Comment: +1 for actually parsing the intent of the question. **Edit**: It turns out it was time for me to learn more perl syntax

Comment: Since I want to assign and not print, perhaps replace "echo" with ":"?  With the help of your answer I was able to find this blog post http://bit.ly/mvNXPf